# Using a Chrome Extension to stop a webpage from loading?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

My eventual goal is to find all resources that the webpage is attempting to load, stop them from loading, and then list them (so that the user can see what the webpage tried to load). Can anyone help me get started with the necessary JavaScript that I'll need to both stop the page from loading and print the resources? I'm just kind of lost on what the first step should be.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at webrequest for chrome extensions:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

I would suggest to create a callback for onBeforeRequest() and then checking what resources are being fetched and loaded.

You can cancel a particular web request from this callback.

Comment: To add to this answer, a concrete example from the docs would be [CatBlock](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/extensions/catblock.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the link! It was great help. However, do you know how to utilize it to block requests to all URLs? I only really see how to block it to a certain one that I specify. And how would I check what resources are being fetched and loaded?